# React Native Yarn - Problems Testing

Tags: macos

I'm trying to get into react native and installed NPM on Mac OS using terminal.

The first tutorial app is weather through create-react-native-app.
Used the command line yarn start.

After scanning the QR code with my iPhone and then showing on the Expo app, I keep getting the same error over and over.

> There was a problem loading the requested app. It looks like you may
>   be using a LAN URL. Make sure your device is on the same network as
>   the server or try using a tunnel.
>
> The experience you requested uses Expo SDK v(null), but this copy of
>   Expo Client requires at least v31.0.0. The author should update their
>   experience to a newer Expo SDK version.

I have checked several times, both desktop and phone is on the same network, firewall is off, IP address is local (192.168...:19000), even tried to open the 19000 port. I've also tried editing the package.json changing the dependencies.

I looked around other posts and haven't found a solution yet.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you.